# Remove customized rows from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, protocols

I'm just practicing with UITableView. 
Here is what I did so far.

- made cells with xib.file from scratch.
- Data is stored in P-list.
- Using `[ MutableCopy]` and convert array into `mutableArray`
- It looks little strange but I made the delegate connection using storyboard ,so there's no "`self.tableView.delegate = self`" line here.

Now the problem is I can delete the objects in the `mutableArray` but not on UI. The row I selected is remained on the table. 
I know  "`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`" delegation method works but something goes wrong.

Any Advice is appreciated! Thanks:)

```
![#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Model.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

    NSMutableArray *_recipesMC;
    NSMutableArray *_imagesMC;

    Model *_model;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    \[super viewDidLoad\];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Model *model = \[\[Model alloc\] init\];
    \[model getBack\];

    NSArray *recipes = model.recipes;
    NSArray *images = model.imagesArray;

    _recipesMC = \[recipes mutableCopy\];
    _imagesMC = \[images mutableCopy\];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    \[super didReceiveMemoryWarning\];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



# pragma mark delegat patern


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return \[_recipesMC count\];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";


    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)\[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier\];


    if(cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = \[\[NSBundle mainBundle\] loadNibNamed:@"Empty" owner:self options:nil\];
        cell = \[nib objectAtIndex:0\];

    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = \[_recipesMC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row\];

    if (indexPath.row < \[_recipesMC count\] - 1)
    {
        UIImage *image = \[UIImage imageNamed:_imagesMC\[indexPath.row\]\];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;

    }


    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;

}


# pragma mark delegate touch


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%li",(long)indexPath.row);

    UIAlertView *alert = \[\[UIAlertView alloc\] initWithTitle:@"HEY" message:\[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recipesMC\[indexPath.row\]\] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil\];
    \[alert show\];

    UITableViewCell *cell = \[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath\];

    if (cell.accessoryType !=
        UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {


        cell.accessoryType =
        UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }


    \[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CellSelectionSegue" sender:self\];

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Clicked DELETE BUTTON at %i",indexPath.row);

    \[_recipesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row\];
    \[_imagesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row\];

    \[self.tableView reloadData\];

    NSLog(@"count = %i",\[_recipesMC count\]);

}



# pragma mark Segue

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue");
}


@end
```

Comment: Are you sure `self.tableView` isn't `nil` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `self.tableView` is `nil`.

It's because even if you set self as datasource and delegate, your table will work, but here you seems to have create your `UITableView *tableView` but didn't link it through your interface (if you do it with the builder).

Or you can simply call `tableView` rather than `self.tableView` because the delegate protocole gives you the table.

Just do it and it will work. And then, you can try the solution of Szu.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Clicked DELETE BUTTON at %i",indexPath.row);

    [_recipesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_imagesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"count = %i",[_recipesMC count]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed connecting self.tableView to the interface builder.

Comment: The both of them work pretty well. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yo should call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath:wothRowAnimation:`

e.g. in my code:

```
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ElKeyValuePair *pair = [self.locationFavoritesKeyArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.locationFavoritesKeyArr removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        ELCarpark *carpark = [self.agglomeration carparkForUid:[pair.val1 intValue]];
        [carpark removeFromFavoritesAgglomerationUid:self.agglomeration.uid];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Comment: Since he calls `reloadData`it's not needed. It seems that his `reloadData`doesn't work.

Comment: yeah that's right. I just don't understand why reloadData doesn't work. It know the method should work, but at that time the tableView   didn't retrieve data from plist and didn't use xib.file to modify cells.

Comment: No problem :-) You should avoid calling reloadData where it's possible. reloadData takes much time and also don't show some row animations.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to the method `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` should remove the row from the data source and the UI.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
[_recipesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[_imagesMC removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES];
}
```

Finally remove the `reloadData` instruction.